# Track image response time in Picasso android - Get the network request start time

Tags: android, picasso

I have a recyclerview in which I load image from server using Picasso. To track the response time of each image I am saving the time I made the call to picasso, and in picasso's onSuccess() callback I will get the final time. The problem is that all the image requests to server(network) will not start at same time even-though we call multiple requests to picasso, since there is limitation in the number of asynchronous network requests (which is normal ).

**Is there any way to get the network request start time using picasso** itself, without affecting performance much.

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(image)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
.into(imageView, new ImageTimeTracker(image));
```

my image tracker will implement picasso callback `com.squareup.picasso.Callback`.
In constructor I will get the start time

```
ImageTimeTracker(String url){
   start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   this.url = url;
}
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.i(TAG, "time for "+url+" = "+(end-start)+"ms");
}
```

But it will become cumulative if I have many image request at same time.